# jQuery: Grabbing form data

Tags: jquery

```
    $('.chat').submit(function() {
        $.post("", $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
            $(this).closest('.stake_chat').prepend(???);
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Where ??? is I would like to output the chat message, the name="chat_message" field in the form.

The post serializes the forms data and pass it to the same site; I need the data of name="chat_message" to prepend in the .stake_chat class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the AJAX success callback `this` is not what you think it is. It is not the form. It represents the xhr object. You could capture the form in a closure if you want to use it inside the callback:

```
$('.chat').submit(function() {
    var $form = $(this);
    $.post('', $form.serialize(), function(response) {
        $form.closest('.stake_chat').prepend(response);
    });

    return false;
});
```

or use the context parameter with `$.ajax`:

```
$('.chat').submit(function() {
    var $form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $form.serialize(), 
        context: $form,
        success: function(response) {
            this.closest('.stake_chat').prepend(response);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

And to get the input that's inside the form with a given name you could use the following selector:

```
$('input[name="chat_message"]', $form)
```

Comment: You might want to look at `context` property in `post` big brother- `ajax`

Comment: @DarinDimitrov oh, thanks i forgot that. Although my issue was not really there. See: http://jsfiddle.net/cALCm/ I would like to output the text you just entered in the div element at the top. Thing is there is more <forms> and .stake_chats like this, and therefore I cant just do $('.stake_chat').prepend(); since it will go into every elements with .stake_chat. I would only like to prepend to the .stake_chat that is above the form (that is closest). And how do i prepend the message?

Comment: $('input[name=chat_message]').val() will not work either because I want the input that is inside the $form, and not all of them.

Comment: Then use the `$('input[name="chat_message"]', $form)` selector. I have updated my answer to illustrate this.

Comment: @Karem, it's not working because the form is outside of the div with `class="stake_chat"`. The `.closest` function search for parent elements. I have updated your fiddle with a working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/cALCm/2/ And if you want the form to be outside of the div then simply give this div an unique id and then use an id selector instead of the .closest function.